# Colocar valor coluna table em um input

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho uma tabela com 4 colunas e vários registros. Nesta mesma tabela tenho um botão para cada registro.

Ao clicar neste botão gostaria de pegar o valor de uma coluna e colocar em um inputText.

Codigo:

```
    <input type="text" class="senha">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>

                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Mês/Ano</th>
                    <th>Senha</th>
                    <th>Máquina</th>
                    <th>Validade</th>
                </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            $i = 0;

            while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $i += 1;
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo mes_extenso($linha['mes']) .'/' .$linha['ano']; ?></td>                            
                    <td><?php echo $linha['senha_mensal']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $linha['nome_maquina']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($linha['validade'])); ?></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><a class='btn btn-info btn-xs'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Copiar
                        <?php $linha['senha_mensal']; ?> </a></td>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Poste o codigo da tabela que vc já tem

Comment: Editei a mensagem colocando o código da tabela;

Comment: Assim que puder respondo aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue a resposta:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Example Table Jquery</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-3 panel panel-body'>
                <form class='form' id='myForm' method='post'>
                    <label>ID:</label>
                    <input name='id' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='ID' />

                    <label>Mês/Ano:</label>
                    <input name='mesano' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Mês/Ano' />

                    <label>Senha:</label>
                    <input name='senha' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Senha' />

                    <label>Máquina:</label>
                    <input name='maquina' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Máquina' />

                    <label>Validade:</label>
                    <input name='validade' type='datetime' class='form-control' placeholder='Validade' />

                    <hr>

                    <input class='btn btn-sm btn-info' type='reset' value='Limpar' />
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class='col-md-9'>
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Mês/Ano</th>
                            <th>Senha</th>
                            <th>Máquina</th>
                            <th>Validade</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class='dados'>
                        <?php
                        $i = 0;
                        while ($i < 5) {
                            $i += 1;
                            ?>
                            <tr id="r<?php echo $i ?>">
                                <td class='id'><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                                <td  class='mesano'><?php echo "mes/ano - {$i}"; ?></td>                            
                                <td><?php echo "senha - {$i}"; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo "maquina - {$i}" ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo "validade - {$i}" ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <a id="<?php echo $i ?>" class='btn btn-info btn-xs copiar'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>Copiar</a>
                                </td>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src='jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(function()
            {
                $('.copiar').click(function()
                {
                    var id = this.id;
                    $('input[name = id]').val( $('#r' + id + ' td:nth-child(1)').text() );
                    $('input[name = mesano]').val( $('#r' + id + ' td:nth-child(2)').text() );
                    $('input[name = senha]').val( $('#r' + id + ' td:nth-child(3)').text() );
                    $('input[name = maquina]').val( $('#r' + id + ' td:nth-child(4)').text() );
                    $('input[name = validade]').val( $('#r' + id + ' td:nth-child(5)').text() );

                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Há diversas maneiras de se fazer isso, fiz da mais simples, mapeando todos elementos da tabela que uso com ids únicos, assim posso saber que o botão daquela linha foi selecionado e então preencher os campos com o valor daquela coluna. Editei o código para funcionar sem o banco de dados para que os outros membros também tenham condição de testar.

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira mais simples de se fazer isso (partindo do principio que jQuery é uma opção) é utilizando o método [`.closest()` do jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), que retorna na arvore `DOM` e seleciona o próximo elemento pai conforme seletor.

Algo similar a isso (exemplo funcional):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.copiar').click(function(event) {
    var copyValue =
      // inicia seletor jQuery com o objeto clicado (no caso o elemento <a class="copiar">)
      $(event.target)
      // closest (https://api.jquery.com/closest/) retorna o seletor no tr da linha clicada 
      .closest("tr")
      // procura a <td> com a class target-copy
      .find("td.target-copy")
      // obtem o text no conteúdo do elemento <td>
      .text()
      // remove possiveis espaços no incio e fim da string
      .trim();

    // seleciona o input com id=senha
    $('#senha')
      // seta o valor copiado para o input id=senha
      .val(copyValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="senha">
<div>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Mês/Ano</th>
        <th>Senha</th>
        <th>Máquina</th>
        <th>Validade</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td>
          01/2016
        </td>
        <td class="target-copy">
          123456#1
        </td>
        <td>
          maquina1
        </td>
        <td>
          30/01/2016
        </td>
        <td class="text-center"><a class='btn btn-info btn-xs copiar'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Copiar</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
        <td>
          02/2016
        </td>
        <td class="target-copy">
          123456#2
        </td>
        <td>
          maquina2
        </td>
        <td>
          30/02/2016
        </td>
        <td class="text-center"><a class='btn btn-info btn-xs copiar'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Copiar</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          3
        </td>
        <td>
          03/2016
        </td>
        <td class="target-copy">
          123456#3
        </td>
        <td>
          maquina3
        </td>
        <td>
          30/03/2016
        </td>
        <td class="text-center"><a class='btn btn-info btn-xs copiar'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Copiar</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          4
        </td>
        <td>
          04/2016
        </td>
        <td class="target-copy">
          123456#4
        </td>
        <td>
          maquina4
        </td>
        <td>
          30/04/2016
        </td>
        <td class="text-center"><a class='btn btn-info btn-xs copiar'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Copiar</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          5
        </td>
        <td>
          05/2016
        </td>
        <td class="target-copy">
          123456#5
        </td>
        <td>
          maquina5
        </td>
        <td>
          30/05/2016
        </td>
        <td class="text-center"><a class='btn btn-info btn-xs copiar'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Copiar</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[Exemplo também no jsFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/vsu329m2/)

**Alterações em seu código original:**

- No `input` de senha, foi alterado de `class="senha"` para `id="senha"`;
- Adicionado ao campo que queremos copiar o conteúdo da linha a `class="target-copy"`;
- Adicionado a botão copiar a `class` `"copiar"`;
- Adicionado biblioteca jQuery;
- Adicionado código `javascript` para função de `click` no botão.